# React-Redux: filtering an array of objects from state by whether their properties match other arrays from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a connected React component which gets an array of Plot objects from state.

It also gets several arrays of strings from state. Like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        plots: state.plots.plots,
        varietyFilter: state.plots.varietyFilter,
        regionFilter: state.plots.regionFilter,
        growerFilter: state.plots.growerFilter,
        plotNameFilter: state.plots.plotNameFilter
    };
}
```

Each plot looks something like this:

```
{ name, variety, region, grower}
```

...with each property being a string.

I want to filter the plots by whether the appropriate properties are in those filter arrays.

The standard solution is to use something like

```
const filteredArray = inputArray.filter( a => filterArray.indexOf(a.property)
```

There are three problems I have with this approach. First, if the filter array is empty, no elements of the filtered array will pass, while I want them all to pass. Second, what happens when those filter arrays, which show up from state, have not yet been initialized? There will be an error, since indexOf in not available. Third, I want to chain these filter methods, but only chain the ones which have some sort of filter array initialized.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
if (this.props.plots) {
            filteredProps = this.props.plots.filter(function(plot) {
                if (!varietyFilter.indexOf) {
                    return true;
                }
                return varietyFilter.indexOf(plot.variety) > -1;
            });
        }
```

That just seems to pass everything through, though. If I remove the first return statement, I get an error-the indexOf method is not there when the component first initializes.

So, two questions. First, how do I filter an array of objects for whether a given property of each object is included in an array of strings which may or may not exist in state? Second, how do I do this for a series of arrays, each corresponding to a different property of the objects in the original array?

Comment: Could you please provide typical values of each of the variables you're working with? I.e plots & filters? I'm still not sure if we're dealing with arrays of objects or with objects containing arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let pass all elements if filterArray is an empty array and to prevent errors if it's null or undefined, you can do:

```
const filteredArray = inputArray.filter( a => (filterArray || []).length === 0 || filterArray.includes(a.property));
```

The code below set an empty array as a default value of filterArray in case it's null or undefined:

```
filterArray || []
```

And the part below do the filtering if array length is positive:

```
|| filterArray.includes(a.property)
```

These codes are equivalents to:

```
const filteredArray = inputArray.filter( a => {
    if (!filterArray) {
        filterArray = [];
    }
    if (filterArray.length === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return filterArray.includes(a.property);
    }
}
```

Chaining mutliple filters can be done by:

```
var filters = [
    { prop: 'prop1', filterArray: ['abc', 'def'] },
    { prop: 'prop2', filterArray: ['abc'] },
    { prop: 'prop3', filterArray: ['abc', 'cde'] }
];

var filteredArray = [...inputArray];   // Copy inputArray

filters.forEach(filterObj => {
    filteredArray= filteredArray.filter( a => (filterObj.filterArray || []).length === 0 || filterObj.filterArray.includes(a[filterObj.prop]));
});
```

Comment: Two questions:
1) Why are we checking if the length of either a filterArray OR a blank array is 0? Will it not always return true for this check, since the length of a blank array is always 0? 
2) How does just checking filterArray.indexOf(a.property) work? Why do we not need to check if the indexOf value is more than -1?

Comment: 2) I've changed to use array.prototype.includes (it returns true or false). With indexOf, it should be filterArray.indexOf(a.property) !== -1  1) In case the array is not blank, filterArray || [] evaluates to filterArray itself and the length is positive so(filterArray || []).length === 0 evaluates to false and the final return is filterArray.includes(a.property)

Comment: That's beautiful. Thank you-I really get a good feeling when I see people with such a grasp of ES6 features.